# How to prevent duplicates in an SQL cross-query

Tags: sql, duplicates

so Here's my query:

```
SELECT b1.beer as beer1, b2.beer as beer2
, b1. price as price1, b2.price as price2 (b1.price+b2.price) as pair
, b1.bar as bar
FROM `beer`.`sells` b1, `beer`.`sells` b2
WHERE b1.beer <> b2.beer AND b1.bar = b2.bar;
```

I want to query every distinct pair of beers that a bar serves, the price of each beer, and their combined price, without printing duplicate pairing form the same bar.

I.E. Not this:

```
beer1     beer2     price1    price2    pricepair    bar
Bud       Coors     2.50      2.00      4.50         The Bar
Coors     Bud       2.00      2.50      4.50         The Bar
Coors     Yuengling 1.50      2.00      3.50         Bar Seven
Yuengling Coors     2.00      1.50      3.50         Bar Seven
```

Rather, this:

```
beer1    beer2     price1    price2    pricepair    bar
Bud      Coors     2.50      2.00      4.50         The Bar
Coors    Yuengling 1.50      2.00      3.50         Bar Seven
```

I tried SELECT DISTINCT, but no good.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have 2 beers per bar, you can always use

```
SELECT b1.beer as beer1, b2.beer as beer2, b1. price as price1, b2.price as price2 (b1.price+b2.price) as pair, b1.bar as bar
FROM `beer`.`sells` b1, `beer`.`sells` b2
WHERE b1.beer < b2.beer AND b1.bar = b2.bar;
```

So the beer1 will be the one first in the alphabetic order

Answer (score 1):

How about using b1.beer < b2.beer in your where clause?